# ioremap returns NULL

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to create a customised UART driver for Raspberry PI.
I try to ioremap the MMIO. But `ioremap` returns always `NULL`.

```
#define UART_REG_BASE_ADDR  0x7E20100

pUart = ioremap(UART_REG_BASE_ADDR, 1024);
if (pUart==NULL)
{
    printk("Couldn't remap UART MMIO\n");
    return -EIO;
}
```

`dmesg` dumps following:

```
[ 2906.579848] CPU: 0 PID: 4983 Comm: insmod Tainted: G      D W  O   3.18.5+ #1
[ 2906.590783] [<c0014b64>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c00120ec>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[ 2906.614046] [<c00120ec>] (show_stack) from [<c0549008>] (dump_stack+0x20/0x28)
[ 2906.624803] [<c0549008>] (dump_stack) from [<c0022620>] (warn_slowpath_common+0x7c/0x9c)
[ 2906.647925] [<c0022620>] (warn_slowpath_common) from [<c002266c>] (warn_slowpath_null+0x2c/0x34)
[ 2906.668656] [<c002266c>] (warn_slowpath_null) from [<c001a888>] (__arm_ioremap_pfn_caller+0x240/0x25c)
[ 2906.691936] [<c001a888>] (__arm_ioremap_pfn_caller) from [<c001a934>] (__arm_ioremap_caller+0x68/0x70)
[ 2906.713171] [<c001a934>] (__arm_ioremap_caller) from [<c001a3d0>] (__arm_ioremap+0x24/0x2c)
[ 2906.735043] [<c001a3d0>] (__arm_ioremap) from [<bf19c028>] (hello_init+0x28/0x88 [domotx])
[ 2906.755780] [<bf19c028>] (hello_init [domotx]) from [<c000873c>] (do_one_initcall+0x94/0x1e4)
[ 2906.778165] [<c000873c>] (do_one_initcall) from [<c0087e70>] (load_module+0x1848/0x1e38)
[ 2906.799410] [<c0087e70>] (load_module) from [<c008854c>] (SyS_init_module+0xec/0xf0)
[ 2906.822660] [<c008854c>] (SyS_init_module) from [<c000e980>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x48)
[ 2906.844558] ---[ end trace c7cdd8b3d5007a1b ]---
[ 2906.856382] Couldn't remap UART MMIO
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You even got a warning! There is not enough context to understand what is the warning about. It's better to get pieces of code around bf19c028, c001a3d0, c001a934, and c001a888.

Comment: Great! And how do I find back the line number based on PC? Is there somewhere a map file? I ran `objdump -S vmlinux` but that doesn't seem to do the trick. I already dived into `__arm_ioremap_pfn_caller` but there are several places where `NULL` is returned. ps: probably it's already clear but I'm new to linux (kernel drivers).

Comment: how do unmap/disable the driver provided by the OS (linux)? are you using raspbian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for the problem reported above. Actually the solution is two-fold:

- The BCM2835 datasheet does not advertise physical addresses in their datasheet:
  *Physical addresses range from 0x20000000 to 0x20FFFFFF for peripherals. The bus addresses for peripherals are set up to map onto the peripheral bus address range starting at 0x7E000000. Thus a peripheral advertised here at bus address 0x7Ennnnnn is available at physical address 0x20nnnnnn.*
- There is a typo in the datasheet:
  *The PL011 USRT is mapped on base adderss 0x7E20100.* which must be *The PL011 USRT is mapped on base adderss 0x7E20100**0**.*